# IOS: tie SNMP v3 credentials to TACACS or RADIUS?

Tags: cisco, snmp, ios, tacacs+

On Cisco IOS, I'm looking at moving from SNMP v1/2 to v3, which means separate user/password credentials instead of just community strings.

Is it possible to have those user credentials pulled from, and authenticated against, a TACACS or RADIUS server?  Or am I stuck statically adding them to the configuration of every switch and router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but from what I ever see and read, it's not possible at the moment.

Comment: I suspect you're right, and I can see some logic to it: when the monitoring system uses that SNMP Get like a ping, to check if the router is alive, it doesn't want to have to wait for the router to ask a remote server about the credentials.  Still, frustrating to move from "insecure" shared, local community strings to... shared, local u/p strings.